# converting array of objects to json with restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit-0.20

i know how to convert object to json using restkit like

```
User* user = [User new];
user.firstName = @"Blake";
user.lastName = @"Watters";

RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSDictionary class] ];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"firstName", @"lastName"] ];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:mapping objectClass:[User class] rootKeyPath:@"user" method:RKRequestMethodAny];
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *parameters = [RKObjectParameterization parametersWithObject:object requestDescriptor:requestDescriptor error:&error];

// Serialize the object to JSON
NSData *JSON = [RKMIMETypeSerialization dataFromObject:parameters MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON error:&error];
```

case1: if the its not just User object , what if it like NSArray *users ;

case2: if the its not just User object , what if it like NSArray *users and the User class has subclass called courses for example , how to get json to send to web service ;

Comment: Do you have to use restkit?

Comment: i think its more easier and save a lot of time , if not tell me what is the best choice to work with web service (send , get ... etc) in the application ?

Comment: but now i'm working with it

Comment: Take a look at NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Why are you using `RKObjectParameterization` directly? Did you experiment and see what happens?